# Correct Rendering of Overridden TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, treeview, overriding

I was having trouble with the standard Windows Forms TreeView; specifically with the colour with which the default control used to render the selected node when the tree-view did not have focus. This was a light grey that on some screens was almost invisible. Subsequently, I have subclassed the TreeView and overridden the TreeView `OnDrawNode` event to colour my nodes as I wish. This is working well, but now 'HotTracking' (active highlighting when the mouse is over a given tree node) is being over ridden by my custom `OnDrawNode` event. I am not too familiar with the `Graphics` classes and wondered how I can amend my current subclass to include hot tracking? I am aware I could use `e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pen pen, Point p1, Point p2);` but this will get messy, is there an easier way?

Here is the existing code:

```
class CustomTreeView : TreeView 
{
    public CustomTreeView() 
    {
        this.DrawMode = TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawText;
    }

    // Override the drawMode of TreeView.
    protected override void OnDrawNode(DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e) 
    {
        TreeNodeStates treeState = e.State;
        Font treeFont = e.Node.NodeFont ?? e.Node.TreeView.Font;

        // Colors.
        Color foreColor = e.Node.ForeColor;
        string strDeselectedColor = @"#6B6E77", strSelectedColor = @"#94C7FC"; //@"#1ABEE8"; //@"#2FC0EE"; //@"#3A8FEA";
        Color selectedColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(strSelectedColor);
        Color deselectedColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(strDeselectedColor);

        // New brush.
        SolidBrush selectedTreeBrush = new SolidBrush(selectedColor);
        SolidBrush deselectedTreeBrush = new SolidBrush(deselectedColor);

        // Set default font color.
        if (foreColor == Color.Empty)
            foreColor = e.Node.TreeView.ForeColor;

        // Draw bounding box and fill.
        if (e.Node == e.Node.TreeView.SelectedNode) 
        {
            // Use appropriate brush depending on if the tree has focus.
            if (this.Focused)
            {
                foreColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(selectedTreeBrush /*SystemBrushes.Highlight*/, e.Bounds);
                ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(e.Graphics, e.Bounds, foreColor, SystemColors.Highlight);
                TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, treeFont, e.Bounds, foreColor, TextFormatFlags.GlyphOverhangPadding);
            }
            else
            {
                foreColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(deselectedTreeBrush /*SystemBrushes.Highlight*/, e.Bounds);
                ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(e.Graphics, e.Bounds, foreColor, SystemColors.Highlight);
                TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, treeFont, e.Bounds, foreColor, TextFormatFlags.GlyphOverhangPadding);
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            // This is firing but is being over written, perhaps by the above?
            if ((e.State & TreeNodeStates.Hot) == TreeNodeStates.Hot)
            {
                e.DrawDefault = true;
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, e.Bounds);
                TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, treeFont, e.Bounds, System.Drawing.Color.Blue, TextFormatFlags.GlyphOverhangPadding);
            }
            else
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, e.Bounds);
                TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, treeFont, e.Bounds, foreColor, TextFormatFlags.GlyphOverhangPadding);
           }   
        }
    }
```

As always guys, thanks very much for your time.

Comment: *"This was a light grey that on some screens was almost invisible."* So that person's computer is basically unusable, right? Because Windows uses the same inactive highlight color throughout the system and in all other applications. I hope this is a kiosk machine that runs *only* your application, otherwise it's futile to change it. And I don't recommend changing it anyway, because as you've observed, owner drawing makes everything much more difficult. In this case, you'll need to add code to the mouse event handler methods to do the hot-tracking yourself. It won't be automatic.

Comment: Why is it 'futile' to change it? On a white background this inactive highlight colour is a very faint grey, and is not easy to see in some cases (like the problem I outline for the treeView above). The mouse event handler (`MouseMove` or some such event) that deals with the 'HotTracking' is likely to be calling the `OnDrawNode` event to render the nodes - the question still stands. How best to re-implement the 'HotTracking' functionality. Thanks for your time...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pay attention to e.State in your code.  The DrawTreeNodeEventArgs.State property tells you what is going on with the node, pick the colors accordingly.  Also check the MSDN library example shown in the docs for TreeNode.DrawNode for guidance.

Comment: Hans, I am now checking for the selected node. If it is not selected I check to see if the mouse is over the node usng `if ((e.State & TreeNodeStates.Hot) == TreeNodeStates.Hot)` then I attempt to draw the text differently. It is hitting this code but it doesn't seem to be rendering it. Can you give me any other advide? I have ammended the code above to show what I have attempted. Thanks again...

Comment: Why are you setting e.DrawDefault = true?  That will overdraw any painting that you did.

Comment: Ridiculous, school boy stuff! Thanks, absolute class act. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the HotTracking of you TreeView to true and it will work, because in TreeView, the nodes which it contains don't have self identity as control each and every node is draw by TreeView itself while the nodes just contains the data, That's why they don't have events and the TreeView does whole work, So to get these Hot Statuses set

objTreeView.HotTracking = true;

TreeView will start providing you the status and you code will work fine.